# Maven Versions Plugin - Skip running maven versions plugin during mvn build install

Tags: java, maven, version, pom.xml, mvn-repo

Whenever I run mvn clean install I want mvn versions plugin to run, which is how my project currently operates. This is perfect, but sometimes I may want to NOT run maven versions plugin to speed up build time (this case is more the exception that the rule).

But I can't find anyway to skip it... (there's no -DskipVersions=true AFAIK).

Does anyone know how can I skip the execution of only this plugin?

maven-versions-plugin: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/

Comment: First question: Why does it run every time you build? Furthermore the question do you really need `mvn clean install` or would be `mvn clean verify` sufficient...?

Comment: Can you show how you are using the version plugin?

Comment: It runs every time I run mvn clean install because I want it to notify us of available dep updates on every build

Comment: I would run the reporting for new version only once per week or maybe each night once but not for every build...it's wasting time...

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a waste of time. But this does not answer the question, can the plugin execution be skipped with a flag, similar to -Dskiptests=true ?

Comment: No it can not.. and that's the reason why I'm saying that it does not make sense to execute it every time...and the skip request is the symptom that something is wrong...which I like to emphasize..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a maven profile for executing the version maven plugin. When activeByDefault you do not need to add the profile for maven build.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>useVersion</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
             ...
             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
             <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>        
              ...
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

You could disable the profile by using `!`

```
mvn clean install -P !useVersion
```

For further information Llook at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: This did the job, thanks a lot! I just had to add single quotes around the profile name!